# Understanding of PCR Jitter Measurements

Tags: video, video-streaming, networkx, mpeg2-ts, jitter

I am trying to understand the PCR Jitter calculation for an MPEG2 ts video stream. 
By reading the jitter calculation process depends on PCRBase and PCRExt and the Jitter value will be in nanoseconds. 
When I tried to decode the PESBase and ext values of the PES packet I got value of order >10^6.

How can I calculate the value of jitter from such large values?(The PCROJ value should be < 500ns)
What is the exact method to calculate the PCR Jitter value?

Answer (score 1):

The ±500 ns tolerance is used for the PCR Accuracy (`PCR_AC`), not for the PCR Overall Jitter (`PCR_OJ`). This means it doesn't include any network-induced jitter. The overall jitter can be a lot greater than the accuracy limit.

A good answer is too long to include here, take a look at this [primer](http://www.tek.com/dl/25W_14617_1.pdf).

Comment: In my application I am observing the PCR Overall Jitter as big as 10^9. I am surprised by seeing the value.

Comment: Is PCR packet(Packet containing PCR data will be only video or will it be either video/audio) ?